# Trying to see if a Custom Field Value starts with any names from a Custom Metadata Type

Tags: apex, list, custom-metadata

I'm extremely new to APEX, but it seemed like this was a simple enough requirement.

I have a custom field on the Account Record, and a list of 'bad codes' as a custom metadata setting. I need the APEX to check if the custom field on the Account starts with any of the Name__c values from the Custom Metadata List

Here's my code so far. It saved, but it doesn't update anything on the Account Record when I make an edit.

Any help, resources, or direction is greatly appreciated.

```
public class NaicsExclusion {

public static void CompareCodes(Account[] acc){
for (Account a :acc){
    List<NAICS_Exclusion__mdt> BadCodes =
        [SELECT Name__c FROM NAICS_Exclusion__mdt];
        for(NAICS_Exclusion__mdt BC : BadCodes) {
            System.debug('Name__c: ' + BC.Name__c);
            if (a.NaicsCode.StartsWith(BC.Name__c)) {
                a.isNAICSBad__c = true;
                Update a;
            }
            else {
                a.isNAICSBad__c = false;
                update a;

            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the trigger code:

```
trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, after insert, before update, 
after update)  
{
Trigger_Controls__c triggerSetting = Trigger_Controls__c.getOrgDefaults();

//if true, execute body of code
if(triggerSetting.AccountTrigger__c) {

    //Create an instance of handler class    
    AccountTriggerHandler handler = new AccountTriggerHandler();

    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isInsert){
        system.debug('=== On Before Insert Trigger');

        handler.AccountTriggerRoundRobin(trigger.new, trigger.newMap, 
trigger.oldMap);
        NaicsExclusion.CompareCodes(Trigger.new);
    }

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
        system.debug('=== On After Insert Trigger');    

        handler.updateContactOwner(Trigger.New, null);
        handler.agreementModification(Trigger.New);
        NaicsExclusion.CompareCodes(Trigger.new);

        //Put account Ids into List or Set so that @future method will accept them.
        Map<Id,Account> acctMap = Trigger.NewMap;
        Set<Id> accIds = acctMap.keySet();        
        //Call method which creates Box folder hierarchy
        createBoxFolder.createFolderHierarchy(accIds);
        NaicsExclusion.CompareCodes(Trigger.new);
    }

    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isUpdate){
        system.debug('=== On Before Update Trigger');

       /* handler.AccountTriggerRoundRobin(trigger.new, trigger.newMap, 
trigger.oldMap); */
    }

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
        system.debug('=== On After Update Trigger');

        if( AccountTriggerHandler.runonce() < 5 ){
            handler.agreementModification(Trigger.New);
        }

        //Call the recurssion mechanism - which prevents the functionalities of the 
trigger to be invoked again and again        
        if(globalClass.avoidRecursion('AccountTrigger')){
           //return;
        }            
        handler.updateContactOwner(Trigger.New, Trigger.OldMap);

    }

    if(trigger.isBefore && trigger.isDelete){
        system.debug('=== OnBeforeDelete Trigger');

        //blank
    }

    if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isDelete){
        system.debug('=== On After Delete Trigger');

        //blank
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this from a trigger? Can you include the trigger code?

Comment: Trigger Code added in the initial post

Answer (score 2):

I cleaned up your code a little bit to fix some Bulkifying pitfalls, but to David Reed's point we still need your Trigger code to help you out further:

```
public class NaicsExclusion
{
    public static void CompareCodes(Account[] accs)
    {
        List<NAICS_Exclusion__mdt> BadCodes = [SELECT Name__c FROM NAICS_Exclusion__mdt];

        for(Account a :accs)
        {
            for(NAICS_Exclusion__mdt bc : BadCodes)
            {
                if(a.NaicsCode.StartsWith(bc.Name__c))
                {
                    a.isNAICSBad__c = true;
                    break;
                }else
                {
                    a.isNAICSBad__c = false;
                }
            }
        }

        update accs;
    }
}
```

Comment: you really should pivot the MDT into a map keyed by Name__c so the inner loop is more efficient

Comment: Trying to post the trigger code, but it's a mess too (and too large to post here). I've spent the better part of a year cleaning up as much as I can (I'm the 4th admin in two years)

Comment: @cropredy I actually wanted to change it to a set of Strings, but I wanted to keep it as close to the original code for OP's sake

Comment: I will welcome literally anything to make this work better. All of you are fantastic!

Comment: I'm getting the following error - Variable does not exist: bcSet at line 11 column 20

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my answer

Comment: My target field still isn't getting updated, so I'm guessing it's something with the trigger